# Trigger a programmatically 'checked' checkbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, checkbox, jquery, eventtrigger

I want to trigger a programmatically *checked* checkbox. eg:

```
$(function(){
    //create a trigger that if a checkbox changes, eg is clicked/change show an alert
    $("#idCheckbox").on("change", function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert("Is checked!");
        }
    });

    //onload put it checked
    $("#idCheckbox").attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

The 'problem' is that if I check on load the checkbox by javascript the on() method is not triggered, and the alert is not shown.

The code above is an example, in fact **the script which check the checkbox is not mine** and I can't modify it.

I am using jQuery 1.8.0

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using $('#idCheckbox').trigger('change'); (or click event)? Maybe it's not firing event, only changing state?

Comment: Programmatic changes (i.e. changes made by code rather than user interaction) don't trigger change events, unfortunately.

Comment: The `change` event isn't fired when an attribute of an element is modified.

Comment: So it is not possible?

Answer (score 9):

Rather than setting the attribute to checked you can call `click()` on the checkbox to trigger the the event you had bound previously

---

```
$(function(){
    var $checkbox = $("#idCheckbox");
    $checkbox.on("change", function(){
        if(this.checked){
            alert("Is checked!");
        }
    });

    $checkbox.click();
});
```

---

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/wpLb2/

Comment: I can't do $("#idCheckbox").click();
Is another script different than mine which check the check-box. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can move your inline defined function to global scope and call it:

```
function checkBoxClick(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert("Is checked!");
    }
}

$(function(){
    //create a trigger that if a checkbox changes, eg is clicked/change show an alert
    $("#idCheckbox").on("change", checkBoxClick);

    // Trigger your click function
    checkBoxClick();    

    //onload put it checked
    $("#idCheckbox").attr("checked", "checked");


});
```

Answer (score 1):

When a checkbox is checked programmatically using javascript, onchange event does not get fired automatically. So the script that marks the checkbox as checked should call onchange event.